# Sending the managedObjectContext to viewController crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, segue, managedobjectcontext

I am trying to send my managedObjectContext from my masterViewController to anotherController via a segue and I am always getting this error:

```
-[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d67c70
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d67c70'
```

I am getting the managedObjectContext from my appDelegate in the `viewDidLoad()` of the masterViewController like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

I cant possibly think of anything I could have done wrong anymore, please help.

Comment: show your declaration part of managedObjectContext in masterViewController

Comment: Did you declare `managedObjectContext` in the master view ?

Comment: It is declared like this: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` I have also tried the retain option but still nothing.

Comment: Is MasterViewController have base of UINavigationController? Is property managedObjectContext fill in anyother place?

Comment: Why are you setting the property on the navigation controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the view controller with the managedObjectContext property is embedded in a navigation controller. In the segue method, make sure you grab a reference to the correct view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)navController.topViewController;

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        vc.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it, I totally forgot that I have a navigationController before the otherController.

Answer (score 0):

you call a setter method on UINAvigationController which only exists if you created a property managedObjectContext. So you would have to subclass the UINavigationConroller, create the property and then you should be able to set it from another class.